# Need Secure way to Login VMs

Tags: login, secure

I am a manager working in an IT company.

We have more than 1000 Vms in Live and accessed by lot of people.

We need to have a Secure way to Login the vm without sharing the password to our team.

Linux / Windows we need to Keep the Login as secure and Provide the solution to track/store the commands which they are executing inside the vms.

Request you to share your inputs.

Regards,
Santhosh

Answer (score 1):

Set up your VMs to authenticate via LDAP/AD.

Your Windows VMs should be joined to your domain already so you can login via AD, and Linux supports logging in with an AD account as well with [`sssd`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/sssd-ad).